# Can't shift the origin in python..?

Tags: python

```
a=[3,4]
b=[5,8]
c=[7,4]
d=[a,b,c]
print (d)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):


        d[i][j]-=a[j]


print (d)
```

In this python code the output is

```
[[0,0], [5,8], [7,4]]
```

instead of

```
[[0,0], [2,4], [4,0]]
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Why you expect `[[0,0], [2,4], [4,0]]`?

Comment: Hint: what are the contents of `a` after the first iteration of the outer loop?  (Add a `print` statement to see.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d` contains a reference of `a`, not a copy.

`a` changes from `[3,4]` to `[0,0]` during the first iteration of the loop. That's why, the next iteration of the loop will do `d[i][j]-=[0,0]`.

You should replace `d=[a,b,c]` by `d = [list(a), b, c]`

Comment: so is there any way to get past it other than rewriting a after i for-loop

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh You just should replace `d=[a,b,c]` by `d = [list(a), list(b), list(c)]` and the problem would be solved because `a` won't change anymore.

Comment: `d = map(list, [a, b, c])` would be a bit neater

Comment: also, he only really needs to copy `a` so `d = [list(a), b, c]` would work too

Comment: Could also use `d = [a[:], b, c]` to make a copy of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have got the logical error in your code.

If you want the output as : `[[0,0],[2,4],[4,0]]`, change line 4 to
`d = [list(a), b, c]` or a better expression would be `d = [list(a), list(b), list(c)]`.